# How to put a picture, text and button into a banner?

Tags: image, button, banner

I am trying to create a banner with a picture of an playing card to the left, in the middle I want the text "Games research" and finally a button to the right (Questionary).

I have managed so far is to put the picture of the card and the text, but the button will not appear at the right place:

```
<div id="banner2">
<center><h1>Game research</h1></center>
<a href="Questionary.htm" class='button'>Questionary</a>
</div>


  #banner2 {
   position: center;
   background-image: url(img2/ugluspil3.png);
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 50px;
   z-index: -1;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this a couple ways

One is to make the button float right

```
#banner2 a {
    float: right;
}
```

but be careful to clear your floats after